# R crashes during reading Excel files

Tags: r, datatables, out-of-memory, data-manipulation

Good Afternoon!

Currently at work I'm involved in analyzing Bank's registers (I have downloaded a lot of .xlsx files [average size of 1 file is about 400MB] that should be combined in one big dataframe in order to perform data manupulation procedures and calculate indicators).

Assume I have two tables:

```
table1 <- read_excel("file_1.xlsx")
```

```
table2 <- read_excel("file_2.xlsx")
```

In order to combine them (it is not necessary in my case to opt for join operators as I want to create just a big dataframe) I use rbindlist function from data.table library:

```
l = list(table1, table2)
```

```
table_c <- rbindlist(l)
```

It is much more efficient in terms of memory allocation as I have already dicovered earlier that usual rbind function. But the problem is that when I'm trying to combine, let's say 20 registers (first table is about 18GB (it contains data from 19 already combined registers) and the second one, which is placed down the big one, is about 400MB) I see the problem: "The previous R session was abnormally terminated due to an unexpected crash".

I have read a lot of forums and suggestions: some people say this is because of memory allocation problem (I work in a cloud, and the machine is quite efficient, but the analysis really showed that R consumes a lot of memory that is available for me); some recommend to quite R session and delete all R.History files - these also did not work for me.

Could you please give me a solution to load and combine data in order not to face with this problem?

Thank you very much in advance[image]

Comment: How much memory do you have available? If your table is 18 GB, I would expect you will need at least 32 to 64 GB of available memory for R to work well.

Comment: Thank you for the answer! I work in the cloud, and it is said that the overall available memory is equal to 500GB. When I’m trying to join the tables using rbindlist function (given their size) the system uses around 370GB of memory, and R crashes..